# Find common ids against all dates python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two columns in a dataframe. ID and date. I want to find the IDs that are common for all given dates. There are a lot of ways/solutions to solve this problem. I'm wondering if there is a built-in function in python or pandas or numpy that can do the job for me. Let me show you by example:

```
  Date       Id
2019-04-01   334
2019-04-01   335
2019-04-01   336
2019-04-02   334
2019-04-02   335
```

The answer in this case is:

```
  Date       Id
2019-04-01   334
2019-04-01   335
2019-04-02   334
2019-04-02   335
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape and remove columns with missing values, so get only values exist per each groups:

```
df = (df.groupby(['Date','Id'])
        .size()
        .unstack()
        .dropna(axis=1)
        .stack()
        .index
        .to_frame(index=False))
print (df)
         Date   Id
0  2019-04-01  334
1  2019-04-01  335
2  2019-04-02  334
3  2019-04-02  335
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way `transform` + `nunique`

```
df[df.groupby(['Id'])['Date'].transform('nunique')==df.Date.nunique()]
Out[208]: 
         Date   Id
0  2019-04-01  334
1  2019-04-01  335
3  2019-04-02  334
4  2019-04-02  335
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional selection:

```
df.loc[df['column'] == value]
```

where `column` is the name of the column, and `value` is the value you want to search by. This will return another dataframe with only the rows that you selected. You can use other conditional operators like `!=` with this same approach too.